# Error in linux cross compilation u-boot

Tags: bootloader, u-boot

When i am cross compile u-boot code in ubuntu and gives command as follow

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi- distclean
```

error is:

> System not configured -see readme Error[1]

What is solution for this?

thank you.
hardik gajjar

Comment: What is an *"x-loder"*?  Try either `make distclean` or `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-`, rather than the whole thing.  But you probably need to configure U-Boot for a board, e.g. `make myboard_config`.  The [U-Boot manual](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootConfiguration)

Comment: Looks like the u-boot is NOT configured for a board yet. Hence distclean is NOT required right now. @sawdust x-loader and u-boot are 1st and 2nd stage boot-loaders respectively.

Answer (score 1):

To compile U-Boot, the easiest way is to export the CROSS_COMPILE variable :

```
 $ export CROSS_COMPILE=/directory/.../arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

And then you have to choose the board configuration, for example :

```
$ make lpc4350-board_config
```

Then you can compile :

```
$ make
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`distclean`** target is used to undo/clear any changes made to the local working directory by selecting any board/device-specific config.

The error **`System not configured -see readme Error[1]`** indicates that the current u-boot working-directory is NOT yet configured for any device/board and hence the `distclean` target to **`make`** is redundant at this point.